# Does differentiablity of mod of a continuous function implies differentiablity of the function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on an open interval, and $|f|$ is differentiable. Is $f$ differentiable?

If answer is yes, please give me a proof of it.

If answer is no please give me a counterexample.

What is the role of open interval here? Is the result unchanged for a closed interval?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for a continuous real-valued $f$, the differentiability of $\lvert f\rvert$ implies the differentiability of $f$ (but not vice versa).

If $f(x_0) \neq 0$, we have a neighbourhood $(x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$ of $x_0$ on which $f$ has no zeros, by the continuity. Hence on $(x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$, we have either $f \equiv \lvert f\rvert$ (if $f(x_0) > 0$) or $f \equiv -\lvert f\rvert$. In either case, $f$ is differentiable on $(x_0-\varepsilon, x_0+\varepsilon)$.

If $f(x_0) = 0$, then $\lvert f\rvert$ has a minimum in $x_0$, hence $\lvert f\rvert'(x_0) = 0$, which means

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\lvert f(x_0+h)\rvert}{h} = 0,$$

but that implies

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)}{h} = 0,$$

which is the differentiability of $f$ in $x_0$ with $f'(x_0) = 0$.

So $f$ is differentiable in all points.

If $f$ is defined on a closed (or semi-closed) interval instead of an open interval, the only thing that changes is that in the endpoints of the interval it may be necessary to speak of the one-sided derivative, if the derivative is only defined for interior points.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Fischer for this answer. Proof is clear to me. Here role of open interval is to find the out the nbd $(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$.

Comment: If the interval is closed, and $x_0$ is an end-point of the interval, the neighbourhood would be $[x_0, x_0+\varepsilon)$ or $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0]$. That wouldn't change anything important.